# How to render base64 image in JSPDF?

Tags: reactjs, jspdf

If I replace png with jpeg, it show the pdf but do not show photo/image and the current code show a blank pdf. My code is below which show a pic.

`if (data?.photo) { doc.addImage(data?.photo, 'PNG', pageWidth - 140, 120, 100, 120);  }`

Comment: wich is the type of the image you're trying to add?

Comment: actually it is already received from api in format "data:image/png;base64..."

Comment: You're receiving a base64 `image/png` image and trying to add it as a `image/jpeg`, perhaps there's some validation on `jspdf` to prevent mistakes like this and don't allow adding the image.

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter how images are tagged in jsPDF here they are "wrong" descriptions in every permutation and still work.

What is critical is how those variables are inserted, they must be valid dataurl within the carrier page. You can test your data at https://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/index.html

[image]

```
// Don't forget, that there are CORS-Restrictions. So if you want to run it without a Server in your Browser you need to transform the image to a dataURL
// Use dataurl
var doc = new jsPDF();
var pageWidth = 210;
var dataphoto = "data:image/jpeg;base64,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"


doc.setFontSize(30);
doc.text("Example for Muhammad Abbas Khan", 20, 25);
doc.addImage(dataphoto, "JPEG", pageWidth - 140, 120, 100, 120);
```

[image]

Comment: Actually the pic format is base64. The image loads on "onload" method but pdf did not show it and there is no error, warning. Don't know why it is not showing